# PHP preg_replace with special characters

Tags: php, regex

I have content like the following that I need to run a preg_replace on:

```
Test Title|
test content

John's title - has a hyphen|
john's content

Last one... I promise|
last content
```

I am using the following preg_replace regex on the content to get all the lines ending in "|" and wrapping it with an  tag.

```
preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-'\,-\d\s\w]+\|)/", '<h3 id="${1}">${1}</h3>', $content);
```

The problem I am having is that the regex is not grabbing the hyphen or ellipses. I have inherited this code from another developer so i am more than willing to trash it and start over, but wanted to try to make it work if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could simplify your regex a bit:

`preg_replace("/([^|\n\r]+\|\n)/", '${1}', $content);`

Answer (score 1):

That regex just seems to have a lot of unnecessary problems.  As Otala said, the hypen isn't escaped, the pipe isn't escaped and it's not looking for periods.  Also it had two  checks for hyphens.

You should simplify it by simply looking for all non-pipe characters up to the pipe:

```
preg_replace("/([^|\r\n]+)\|/", '<h3 id="${1}">${1}</h3>', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

The hyphen isn't being escaped and the regex isn't scanning for periods.

`/([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-'\,\.\-\d\s\w]+\|)/` should work.